# Suppress passed test output in Test::More

Tags: perl, unit-testing, test-more

I have a Perl unit test that outputs "ok" for every passed test.  I find myself scrolling up and up to find the first failed test, since that's the only thing I'm interested in.  I am using Test::More.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use JSONRegex;
use Test::More;
```

I would like only failed tests to appear.  I tried the solution of using

```
perl -MTest::Harness -e 'runtests @ARGV' path/to/test_JSONRegex.pl
```

and it worked.  But I wanted to put that in the shebang line so I could just forget about it.  The shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -MTest::Harness
```

failed with message `Too late for "-MTest::Harness" option at ./test_JSONRegex.pl line 1.`

What is the best way to suppress passed test output while still using `strict` in my script?

Comment: See [How can I redirect the test output from Perl's Test::Simple?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345296/how-can-i-redirect-the-test-output-from-perls-testsimple)

Comment: The equivalent to the command line flag `-MFoo::Bar` that you can use in a script is `use Foo::Bar;`, as documented in [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, yes but that won't work for this specific case, where you only want the module if the script is being run directly from the command line (and not already inside a test harness).

Comment: Thanks for this question - and for the idea running tests **not** with _prove_ but plainly with _perl_ in order to actally get the ok output. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just use the `prove` command to run your test script?

```
prove path/to/test_JSONRegex.pl
```

is basically equivalent to

```
perl -MTest::Harness -e 'runtests @ARGV' path/to/test_JSONRegex.pl
```

but with less typing.

Trying to get the test script to automatically determine whether it's already running inside a test harness is going to be tricky and error prone.

Comment: Thanks!  This is very convenient.

Answer (score 3):

```
-MTest::Harness
```

simply puts

```
use Test::Harness;
```

at the top of your script. But then what? How do you plan on calling `runtests`? This is oh-so-very wrong. If you want to save typing, use `prove` as @cjm mentioned, or create a second small script to run your tests.

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is path/to/test_JSONRegex
BASE="$( dirname "$( readlink -e "$0" )" )"
perl -MTest::Harness -e'runtests @ARGV' "$BASE/test_JSONRegex.pl"
```

Answer (score 3):

Show only errors during testing:

```
Test::More->builder->output("/dev/null")                                        #
```